# How do I load multiple templates with Jquery-templating?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm still working on my Smart Home Web App where all rooms and devices are loaded from a JSON API and shown as bootstrap cards.

The data is loaded from the JSON file with jQuery.

Since there shall be an infinite amount of possible rooms and devices, I want to display these rooms and devices with templates.

Today I stumbled upon [jQuery.loadTemplate](https://codepb.github.io/jquery-template/#:%7E:text=jQuery%20Templating%20is%20a%20jQuery,tags%20to%20hold%20the%20template).

I've saved my template in a seperate file within my 'templates' folder which looks like this:

```
<script id="template_all_rooms_dark_xs" type="text/html">
    <div class="card" style="background-color: #6e6e6e;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <img class ="float-right pt-2 icon_fav favourite" data-data-favid="id" data-src="favsrc"/>
            <h6 class="card-title" style="color: #d1d1d1;" data-content="room"><!--Room: 'obj.room'--></h6>
            <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2" style="color: #ffffff;" content="name"><!--'obj.name'-->></h5>
            <p style="color: #ffffff;">Rating:
                <span class="float-right p-1"><img class="rating rating5" data-data-rating5id="id" data-src="rating5src"/></span>
                <span class="float-right p-1"><img class="rating rating4" data-data-rating4id="id" data-src="rating4src"/></span>
                <span class="float-right p-1"><img class="rating rating3" data-data-rating3id="id" data-src="rating3src"/></span>
                <span class="float-right p-1"><img class="rating rating2" data-data-rating2id="id" data-src="rating2src"/></span>
                <span class="float-right p-1"><img class="rating rating1" data-data-rating1id="id" data-src="rating1src"/></span>                
            </p style="color: #ffffff;">
            <select class="custom-select mb-3" style="background-color: #696969; border: none; color: #ffffff;">
                <option data-content="select_1"></option>
                <option data-content="select_2"></option>
                <option data-content="select_3"></option>
                <option data-content="select_4"></option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="switch" data-data-switchid="id" src="switchsrc"/></a>
            <h5 class="card-text pt-2" style="color: white;">Main Switch</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Within my javascript file, I'm loading the template with data like so:

```
$("#container_all_rooms_dark_xs").loadTemplate("templates/all_rooms_dark_xs.htm",{
    id: obj.id,
    favsrc: favsrc,
    room: obj.room,
    name: obj.name,
    rating1src: rating1src,
    rating2src: rating2src,
    rating3src: rating3src,
    rating4src: rating4src,
    rating5src: rating5src,
    select_1: obj.select_1,
    select_2: obj.select_2,
    select_3: obj.select_3,
    select_4: obj.select_4,
    switchsrc: switchsrc
})
```

However, this isn't working whatsoever. Do you have any suggestions or better options?

Comment: Note that plugin has not been developed for quite a few years. You might want to look at a more active one like handlebars.js

Comment: yeah... it's 2020, we have [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) built into javascript now. no need for a plugin if all you want is templating.